# How to install Kubernetes PKI certificates in AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created an AKS cluster. Is Azure generating the following PKI certificate for us?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/#how-certificates-are-used-by-your-cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, AKS manages all these certificates for you, with the exception of:

> Client certificates for administrators of the cluster to authenticate to the API server

Because AKS hands out access tokens in the form of JWTs.